# Excel IF contains text and does not contain text THEN formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working in an excel sheet where I need to identify specific cells based on the following criteria:

If column A = 'Meeting' AND column B contains 'meeting' BUT column B does not contain 'email' THEN return "In Person Meeting".

So far I have the following, even though the first part is fine in identifying column A criteria, I am unsure of how to search text within a cell that contains 'meeting' but not 'email' in the same row cell.

```
=IF(OR(A2="Activation",A2="Conference",A2="Intro Call",A2="Meeting",A2=""),"Correct to Meeting in Person or Virtual",""),OR(AND(A2="Activation",A2="Conference",A2="Intro Call",A2="Meeting",A2=""),AND(SEARCH("meeting",B2))
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula describes; *If column A = 'Meeting' AND column B contains 'meeting' BUT column B does not contain 'email' THEN return "In Person Meeting".*  `=IF(AND(A2="Meeting",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("meeting",B2)),NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("email",B2)))),"In Person Meeting")`
Hope is useful.